# AzureDevops Api: Get item API with download true return a json

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to download a Git File using C#. I use the following code:

```
Stream response = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
var splitpath = path.Split("/");
Stream file = File.OpenWrite(splitpath[splitpath.Length - 1]);
response.CopyToAsync(file);
response.Close();
file.Close();
```

Following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP), I use the following url:

```
string url = mainurl + name + "/_apis/git/repositories/" + rep + "/items?path=" + path + "&download=true&api-version=6.0";
```

but the file saved contains a json containing different links and information about the git file.

To check if all was working well, I tried to download it in a zip format, using the following url:

```
string url = mainurl + name + "/_apis/git/repositories/" + rep + "/items?path=" + path + "&$format=zip";
```

And it works fine, the file downloaded is a zip file containing the original file with its content...

Can someone help me? Thanks

P.S. I know that I can set IncludeContent to True, and get the content in the json, but I need the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C#, I will give you a C# sample to get the original files:

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace xxx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string OrganizationName = "xxx";
            string ProjectName = "xxx";
            string RepositoryName = "xxx";
            string Personal_Access_Token = "xxx";

            string archive_path = "./"+RepositoryName+".zip";
            string extract_path = "./"+RepositoryName+"";

            string url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+OrganizationName+"/"+ProjectName+"/_apis/git/repositories/"+RepositoryName+"/items?$format=zip&api-version=6.0";
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            //client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.Get);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+Personal_Access_Token);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            //save the zip file
            File.WriteAllBytes("./PushBack.zip", response.RawBytes);

            //unzip the file
            if (Directory.Exists(extract_path))
            {
                Directory.Delete(extract_path, true);
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(archive_path, extract_path);
            }
            else
            {
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(archive_path, extract_path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Successfully on my side:

[image]

Let me know whether this works on your side.

Comment: Very thanks, this is how I temporally resolved the problem, but I prefer to directly download it, without post download process

Answer (score 0):

```
var personalaccesstoken = "xyz....";

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*")); //this did the magic for me

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
        Convert.ToBase64String(
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

    using (Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(                    
         "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/myproj/_apis/git/repositories/myrepoid/items?path=%2Fsrc%2Ffolder%2Ffile.txt&api-version=7.0")) //no download arg
    {                    
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        var text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        return text; // text has the content of the source file
    }
}
```

1. no need for download parameter in the url
2. request headers should not be json